# How to delete a string from all files in a directory

Tags: python

I want all files in directory "path" to have the string "error" removed from them and the result to be saved in the same file that was editted. My current code (below) ends up clearing up the entire file, rather than just removing the string and keeping everything else the same.

```
import os


path = "path"
files = os.listdir(path)
error = "string"


for index, file in enumerate(files):
    with open(os.path.join(path, file)) as fin, open(os.path.join(path, file), "w+") as fout:
        for line in fin:
            line = line.replace(error, "f")
            fout.write(line)
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
import os

path = "path"
files = os.listdir(path)
error = "string"

for index, file in enumerate(files):
    with open(os.path.join(path, file), 'r') as fin:
       d = din.read()
    with open(os.path.join(path, file), "w") as fout:
        d = d.replace(error, "")
        fout.write(d)
```

Comment: or use file.truncate() with r+

Comment: Yikes, don't run that program on any directory containing executables or other binary files you don't want corrupted :)

Comment: thank you very much, this worked, a note for anyone who might use this - on line 9 there is a typo, replace din.read() with fin.read()

Comment: Why are you using enumerate()?

Answer (score -2):

This is the correct way to do this:

```
import os

path = "path"

for file in os.listdir(path):
    if not os.path.isdir(file):
        with open(file, 'r+') as fd:
            contents = fd.read().replace('error', '')
            fd.seek(0)
            fd.write(contents)
            fd.truncate()
```